# For loop iterations & array trouble

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, foreach, indexing

I'm trying to make a *List* of about *5500 teams* and create an object *Team* for each element of the list using this code I got from a tutorial:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Team> teams = new List<Team>();
        teams.Capacity = 5500;            

        for (int y = 1; y <= 5500; y++)
        {
            teams[y] = new Team(y);
        }
    }
```

But I keep getting this error:

> An unhandled exception of type '*System.IndexOutOfRangeException*'
>   occurred in [*my program*].exe
>
> Additional information: **Index was outside the bounds of the array**.

In this program, "*Team*" is a custom class that requires a team number when created (...*new Team([teamnumber])*).

Each teamnumber is their unique identity, so this has to correspond with each team's index in the list.

> ...teams[y] = new Team(y);...

What I'm trying to do is make sure there's a *Team* object created for every element in *teams* so that I don't run into errors later when trying to add an attribute to a certain element. Also, I don't want a "Team 0", this is why I started *y* at *1* in the *for* loop. I've also tried using a *foreach* loop but I get the same error.

I'm using **Visual Studio 2012 Express**. This is a **Windows Presentation Forms** program written in **C#**.

Comment: If you really want an array, use `Team[] teams = new Team[5500];`. But you can use a `List<Team>`, just use `Add` method to append items to your list. Note that both `List<T>` and `T[]` are indexed from `0` through `N-1`, not `1` through `N`.

Comment: I used a List because I find lists to be more accessible than normal arrays. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Yeah, lists are usually better. I misunderstood because you mentioned "array trouble" in the header, but I realize that was maybe simply a reference to the exception message. **Note:** If you like Linq, you can consider `var teams = Enumerable.Range(1, 5500).Select(y => new Team(y)).ToList();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are accessing an empty `List<>`, any access will throw this exception. Setting the capacity will *not* create empty entries.

```
var list = new List<int>(10); // Capacity = 10 but Count = 0
list[0] = 1; // out-of-range exception is thrown
```

You need to `Add()` elements before you can use `teams[index]`

```
for (int y = 1; y <= MAX_TEAMS; y++)
{
   teams.Add(new Team(y));  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are indexed starting from zero, so `teams[5500]` is the 5501st element of the list. The list has capacity of 5500 so that's out of range.

You could increase the `Capacity` to 5501, or use `new Team(y+1)` for `y` from 0 to 5499.

Also, you can get rid of the line where you set the capacity by using a different constructor:

```
List<Team> teams = new List<Team>(5500);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    List<Team> teams = new List<Team>(5500);

    for (int y = 1; y < 5501; y++)
    {
        teams.Add(new Team(y));
    }
}
```

This will work. This is how you initialize and add items to the list.
One of the things to notice is `y < 5501` vs `y <= 5500`. `<=` is a little bit of performance hit because this is `OR` condition on operator.

Initializing the list's capacity is the good idea because it will lead to better performance since list will not need to resize.